# Dict to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

Creaing first time my .csv export from a dict.

My dict has the fllowing structure:

```
dict_all[key] = {
"id_ja" : None, 
"id_nein" : None ,
"ZUW_ja": set(), 
"ZUW_nein": set(), 
"missing_ZUW_ja" : set(), 
"missing_ZUW_nein" : set()
}
```

My .CSV should look like:

```
ID_yes/ID_no, ZUW (this needs to be "ZUW" in every row), missing_ZUW_yes/missing_ZUW_nein and Relation (which needs to be -1 in every row)
```

For

`missing_ZUW_yes/missing_ZUW_nein`

I need to write a single row for each entry in this set. 
That means the other three columns need to be duplicated as long there is as ID inside my `missing_ZUW_yes/missing_ZUW_nein`
Probably the easiest is to iterate over `id_yes` first and in this loop adding a row for each entry in `missing_ZUW_yes`. If the first half is done it might be easier to continue with `id_no` and `missing_ZUW_no`.. am I right with that?

My relevant dict entries look like:

```
dict["LM_Doctor"]= {"id_ja": 122344, "id_nein":122345, "missing_ZUW_ja": 123,132,143,12, "missing_ZUW_ja": 432,64,321}
```

and in the csv it should look like:

```
row 0 = Term ID 1
row 1 = 122344
row 0 = ZUW
row 1 = ZUW
row 0 = Term ID 2
row 1 = first id from missing_ZUW_yes #in this example 123
row 0 = RV
row 1 = -1
```

and row two should look the same except the fact that there should be `132` for `missing_ZUW_yes`

Comment: Can you please give us a minimal reproducible example of your code? What is key for example? State an example for a record in the CSV file as well, please.

Comment: Repeating what says @FelixKleineBösing you should edit your question to be able to answer it. So first give  us the dict minimal example and a csv output minimal example.

Comment: better now? Or need more?